# Google App Engine Python - not the last version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

I've recently downloaded from [**here**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=it) the Python GAE, version 1.8.9. After a successfull installation, when I run the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, this is what I get:

[image]

as you can see it says that I'm not using the latest version.. but I've installed the latest one, 1.8.9!

Any idea? What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: had you installed GAE previously? The timestamp is suggesting you did

Comment: Yes, before installing it I did the "Remove GAE from your PC" procedure.. but nothing changed..